Android Camera doesn't set the orientation EXIF tag
In the storeImage function in the LegacyCamera app of AOSP, there is a call to Exif.getOrientation to obtain the orientation from the image to set it later when storing it. In getOrientation, if the orientation tag is not found in the EXIF data, it returns 0.
I am having a problem with a device I'm working on in which this tag is missing from the pictures the camera app is taking. The images should be stored with orientation 270, meaning that they should look like portrait pictures, but all pictures are being stored with that 0 that the getOrientation function returns at the end, making the function always store the images as landscape pictures.
I have examined some pictures taken from the device using exiftool and they do not have the orientation tag.
Where in the code of LegacyCamera is this tag being set? Where does it take it from?
I have been looking at the configuration files I could find, and they all seem to be configured to 270:
        <MountAngle>270</MountAngle>

So, either this value is not being picked up correctly or I'm not looking in the right place (I'm guessing it's the second one).
What is the file(s) I should modify to have the orientation tag in the exif metadata stored correctly?
